# Running shell script using JSch with sudo option

Tags: java, unix, jsch

I have been using JSch quite successfully till now. Now with one the server I have got some problem. I login to the server with my user account and then I do

```
sudo su - another_user
```

Now I want to execute a shell script with 'another_user' permission. I have checked the sudo option with JSch, but that not helping or I am not able to use that properly.

Any help here will be appreciated